# How to have form redirect on submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect

This is my code:

```
function mySubmit() {
  var myForms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
  var userEmail = document.getElementById("myEmail").childNodes[0].nodeValue;

  for (var t = 0; t < myForms.length; t++){
    myForms[t].s_emailaddress.value = userEmail 
    $.post("http://test.test", $(myForms).eq(t).serialize(), function (data, status) {
      if (status === "success") {
```

I'd like to add a redirect function to this.  For example, all form data should be submitted and upon submission, redirect to www.google.com

Comment: Word to the wise, you should really format your code better. It makes it easier for you and everyone else to read and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (status === "success") {
  window.location = 'https://google.com';
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question. A good answer should stand alone, even if the question is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Some ways to redirect Page:

// Sets the new location of the current window.

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

// Sets the new href (URL) for the current window.

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

// Assigns a new URL to the current window.

```
window.location.assign("http://www.google.com");
```

// Replaces the location of the current window with the new one.

```
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
```